# How to make variable as callable function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two variable and one function.

```
<script> 

function myfunction(a1,a2,a3)
{
    alert(a1+a2+a3)
}

var fname="myfunction";
var fdata="data1,data2,data3";

</script>
```

I want to call function from variable values. like this

```
myfunction('data1','data2','data3')
```

I know how to call function from variable value.

```
window[fname](); //this call myfunction()
```

But don't know how to call function with multiple arguments from variable values?

Give me a solution if you can!

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't have to use the *name* of a function to keep a reference to it. Just use the function directly:

```
var fname = myfunction;
```

Then you can call it:

```
fname('whatever');
```

To pass parameters from that string, you'll have to get them out of the string, a process that will depend on how you've combined the values into a string in the first place. In your example, you could split the string on commas to create an array, and then use `.apply()`

```
fname.apply(null, fdata.split(','));
```

The `.apply()` method accepts an array as the second parameter (the first is a value to be used for `this`), and then calls the function such that the values of the arguments are the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the arguments between the parentheses

```
window[fname]('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

To pass dynamically the arguments by using the `fdata` value, you should use `apply` (like @Pointy suggests).

```
window[fname].apply(null, fdata.split(','));
```

Comment: I have two variable to call the function. How I can make variable fdata as ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')?

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your code to be something like this maybe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunction(a123) {

    // remove the coma if you don't want it.
    var completeData = a123.replace(/,/g, "");

    alert(completeData);
  }

  var fname = "myfunction";
  var fdata = "data1,data2,data3";

  window[fname](fdata);
</script>
```

I hope it helps.